# What to do if you find unwanted users

Tags: support, user-accounts

I found two users on superuser that seem to not want to provide anything to the community.

Sure I can flag any of there answers but the problem is that I don't want to spend all my flags to such joke users.

So what can be done in such a case?

Comment: You don't have to spend all your flags. Usually one is enough for us to take care of it. And how else would you be able to (privately) alert us?

Comment: damn bobbin' bills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can report them on the [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chat room.
2. Flag away. You get new flags tomorrow.